# calculate structure automorphism group in MAGMA

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, magma-cas

Please hint me! Is there any instruction in MAGMA to calculate structure automorphism group by using generators?
for example:

```
> G:=Graph<16| { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 14 }, { 2, 5 }, { 2, 7 }, { 3, 4 }, { 3, 14 },
> { 4, 6 }, { 4, 12 }, { 5, 6 }, { 5, 10 }, { 6, 12 }, { 7, 8 }, { 7, 15 },
> { 8, 9 }, { 8, 15 }, { 9, 10 }, { 9, 11 }, { 10, 11 }, { 11, 13 },
> { 12, 13 }, { 13, 16 }, { 14, 16 }, { 15, 16 }    >;

>  A:=AutomorphismGroup(G);

> Generators(A);

{
    (1, 7)(3, 8)(4, 9)(6, 10)(11, 12)(14, 15),
    (1, 6)(2, 5)(3, 4)(7, 10)(8, 9)(11, 15)(12, 14)(13, 16),
    (1, 11)(2, 13)(3, 9)(4, 8)(5, 16)(6, 15)(7, 12)(10, 14)
}
```

I want to calculate structure of A?
in GAP we have `"StructureDescription"` to calculate structure of  automorphism group:

```
gap> A:=Group([(1,7)(3,8)(4,9)(6,10)(11,12)(14,15),
> (1,6)(2,5)(3,4)(7,10)(8,9)(11,15)(12,14)(13,16),
> (1,11)(2,13)(3,9)(4,8)(5,16)(6,15)(7,12)(10,14)]);

Group([ (1,7)(3,8)(4,9)(6,10)(11,12)(14,15), 
(1,6)(2,5)(3,4)(7,10)(8,9)(11,15)(12,14)(13,16), 
(1,11)(2,13)(3,9)(4,8)(5,16)(6,15)(7,12)(10,14) ])

gap> StructureDescription(A);

"C2 x C2 x C2"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by 'structure'? Are you looking for a presentation for $A$?

Comment: yes, I think it's presentation

Comment: Magma does not have an equivalent of $\mathtt{StructureDescription}$, so you have to use other structural commands, like $\mathtt{ChiefSeries}$, $\mathtt{Centre}$, etc, to calculate the structure. First you would need to convert the automorphism group to a $\mathtt{PCGroup}$ (see Dane's answer) or a permutation group.

Comment: @Mohsen: is there a copy-and-paste error in the GAP example, or we speak about different groups? It looks to me like the 3rd generator in the GAP input lacks the $(6, 15)$ transposition. With that corrected, `StructureDescription(G)` returns `"C2 x C2 x C2"`, that is elementary abelian group of order 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but this might be useful.

Since your group $A$ happens to be solvable, the command PCGroup will give you some easily readable information about your group:

```
PCGroup(A);

GrpPC of order 8 = 2^3
PC-Relations:
    $.1^2 = Id($),
    $.2^2 = Id($),
    $.3^2 = Id($)
Mapping from: GrpPerm: A to GrpPC
```

It looks like your group is elementary abelian of order 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both Magma and GAP at your disposal and if the group in question is not of too large an order, there is a neat little trick I've used a couple of times.
Given a group $G$ in Magma, type the following.

```
IdentifyGroup(G);
```

This will give you two numbers $a,b$ which identifies the group in the Small Groups Library.
Then you can start GAP and type this:

```
G:=SmallGroup(a,b);
StructureDescription(G);
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to calculate automorphism group of order 47 and GAP is not able to solve it, is there any way to use MAGMA?

Comment: A group of order 47 is cyclic.

Comment: no,in MAGMA generators of my group are:(39,40),(28,29),(36,37),(22,23),(40,41),(10,11),(26,27),(24,25),(25,26),(38,39),(12,13),(32,33),(14,15),(13,14),(46,47),(8,9),(4,5),(35,36),(16,17),(34,35),(6,7),(37,38),(29,30),(2,3),(18,19),(20,21),(30,31),(33,34),(27,28),(15,16),(41,42),(19,20),(21,22),(9,10),(44,45),(45,46),(42,43) I want to calculate automorphism group whit this generators and "StructureDescription" is not able to solve it.

Comment: You didn't express yourself well. The elements you gave generate a group of an order which is far too large in order for the group to be identified by the method above.